# CSS floats: Why are my logo's not floating left before the text?

Tags: css, css-float

Total beginner here, learning HTML and CSS (not yet grid and  flexbox). I am trying to make a section with two horizontal blocks consisting of an image/icon to the left and text on the right. Very simple, yet I somehow can't get the icon to float to the left of the text. It is stuck on the line below. What am I doing wrong? or what should I add?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1100px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

#strengths {
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  Display: block;
  background-image: url('./img/mountain-lake.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

#strengths .primary {
  background-color: #ccc7f2;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

#strengths .primary i {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<section id="strengths" class="py-3">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="main-heading">My Strengths</h2>
    <div class="primary">
      <h3 class="sub-heading">Strategic Thinking</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus perspiciatis culpa optio nam, ut maxime voluptatibus magnam amet id cupiditate reiciendis quis mollitia vitae nobis eum corporis! Dicta dolorum delectus repellat dolorem hic quis
        qui illum minima ullam voluptas, reiciendis sed quos asperiores eaque amet velit magnam maxime officiis facere.</p>
      <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="primary">
      <h3 class="sub-heading">Analysis</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus perspiciatis culpa optio nam, ut maxime voluptatibus magnam amet id cupiditate reiciendis quis mollitia vitae nobis eum corporis! Dicta dolorum delectus repellat dolorem hic quis
        qui illum minima ullam voluptas, reiciendis sed quos asperiores eaque amet velit magnam maxime officiis facere.</p>
      <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: So ? did my answer help you ?

Answer (score 2):

Bad idea to use `float`. I suggest you look into `flexbox` asap.

But if you really want to use it, you should change the HTML a little bit.

Think of it this way. You want the icon to be a 'column' and the title together with the text to be another column.

The best way to achieve that is to wrap the text and title inside a HTML element ( most probably a div )

Then you should specify the `width` used inside their parent `.primary`. So for example the icon has 5% and the title and text 95% - 20px which is the margin of the icon.

Also add `float:left` to the `primary` div. Because adding `float:left` to an element ( the icon and text ) gets that element out of the normal flow of the document. ( similar to position:fixed/absolute ) and so, for them to remain ' a part ' of the `primary` div , you need to add `float:left` on that div also.

See below

```css
 * {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .container {
   margin: auto;
   max-width: 1100px;
   overflow: auto;
   padding: 50px;
 }

 #strengths {
   height: 600px;
   margin: auto;
   Display: block;
   background-image: url('./img/mountain-lake.jpg');
   background-size: cover;
 }

 #strengths .primary {
   background-color: #ccc7f2;
   padding: 20px;
   margin: 20px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   opacity: 0.75;
   line-height: 1.4em;
   float:left;
   width:100%;
 }

 #strengths .primary i {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 20px;
   display: inline;
   width:5%;
 }
  #strengths .primary .wrapper {
    float:right;
    width: calc(95% - 20px);
    }
```

```html
<section id="strengths" class="py-3">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="main-heading">My Strengths</h2>
    <div class="primary">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h3 class="sub-heading">Strategic Thinking</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus perspiciatis culpa optio nam, ut maxime voluptatibus magnam amet id cupiditate reiciendis quis mollitia vitae nobis eum corporis! Dicta dolorum delectus repellat dolorem hic quis qui illum minima ullam voluptas, reiciendis sed quos asperiores eaque amet velit magnam maxime officiis facere.</p>
      </div>
      <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn fa-3x">icon</i>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="primary">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h3 class="sub-heading">Analysis</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus perspiciatis culpa optio nam, ut maxime voluptatibus magnam amet id cupiditate reiciendis quis mollitia vitae nobis eum corporis! Dicta dolorum delectus repellat dolorem hic quis qui illum minima ullam voluptas, reiciendis sed quos asperiores eaque amet velit magnam maxime officiis facere.</p>
        </div>
      <i class="far fa-play-circle fa-3x">icon</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```